# How to make something disappear using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following drop down:

```
<select name="chooseLanguage">
    <option>Choose One</option>
    <option value="java">Java</option>
    <option value="php">PHP</option>
    <option value="c++">C++</option>
</select>
```

If ANYTHING is selected from this dropdown other than the default "Choose One" which is of course preselected, then I want this input field to disappear:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
```

How can this be achived using jQuery (if possible with a nice fade effect)?

**EDIT**

My entire code, for some reason none of the answers have worked for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#chooseLanguage").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $("#uploadFile").hide();
    } else {
      $("#uploadFile").show();
    }
  });
});
</script>

<form action="" method="post">

<select name="chooseLanguage" id="chooseLanguage">
  <option>Choose One</option>
  <option value="java">Java</option>
  <option value="php">PHP</option>
  <option value="c++">C++</option>
</select>

<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />

</form>
```

Comment: +1 for nice title, David Copperfield should be a SO user :)

Comment: My example worked. To make your code work, change `$(this).val() == '')` to `($(this).attr("selectedIndex")>0)`. Then it works just as good as my code below.

Comment: Why did you mark Wireblue as the correct answer? His solution didn't work.

Comment: @Gert Oh Geez, sorry Gert I was thinking he wrote that fix comment. I feel very stupid now :(

Comment: No problem. Mistakes happen. But it would be nice with an upvote for my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers are nearly correct, but are missing a minor detail or two. This should hopefully work "out of the box".

```
$(function(){
  $("#chooseLanguage").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $("#uploadFile").hide();
    } else {
      $("#uploadFile").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Just give the "chooseLanguage" select box an ID of "chooseLanguage", and the upload input an ID of "uploadFile".

Comment: I haven't chosen any correct answers yet because none of the answers have worked for me, including yours. Please see my edit in the question, I have posted my entire code. Can you please run it and see why it isn't working?

Comment: Apologies Ron. Because the "Choose One" option was missing a blank value attribute, the IF statement didn't work correctly. Up-voted your answer Gert G.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="uploadFile" />
```

then you can just use `$('#uploadFile').hide()`

as suggested you have also [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) for the opposite effect..

Answer (score 2):

Give the input an `id`, like `id="myupload"`.

Then, simply:

```
$('#myupload').fadeOut('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like:

```
$('select[name="chooseLanguage"]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val())
  {
     $('input[name="uploadFile"]').fadeOut('slow');
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 - Except that checking for `$(this).val()` won't do much good because if there's no `value` set, it returns the text contained in the option (for some browsers anyway).

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#chooselanguage").change(function(){
    if ($("#chooselanguage").attr("selectedIndex")>0) {
      $("#fileupload").fadeOut();
    } else {
      $("#fileupload").fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="chooselanguage" name="chooseLanguage">
  <option>Choose One</option>
  <option value="java">Java</option>
  <option value="php">PHP</option>
  <option value="c++">C++</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it.
Example: find all `<div>` elements that have a CSS class of "product", and animate them to slowly disappear:

```
$("div.product").slideUp('slow').addClass("removed");
```